# How can ViewModels reduce code and logic within my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project in MVC5 with C# and Razor Engine.

One of my views, is huge, ans has hundreds of lines of code, thus making it hard to manage. 
On a previous post this community suggested that I should remove logic from my View and use a ViewModel to have that Logic instead.

However, I fail to see how that helps me. My View shows different information depending on who is seeing it:

```
if ((User.isHelpDesk && Model.MaterialStatusId == MatStatus.A1HelpDeskProductProposal) || (User.isProcurement && Model.MaterialStatusId == MatStatus.A4PurchasingDptValidation))
{
    <!-- Show something here -->
}
else if (User.isHelpDesk || User.isProcurement || User.isDirector || User.isManager)
{
    <!-- Show some other thing here-->
}
```

Now, my view has dozens of conditions like the one before. How can a view model help me reduce the code of the view, so it does not contain logic in the form of `if` and `foreach` blocks?

Comment: The logic of what to display should take place in your Controller. Your ViewModel should be a collection of all of the data that the Controller wants to display on the View.

Comment: a decent blog here (though a bit short) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223547/Three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models
Since moving to viewmodels, I find the logic I need to work with views gets much easier to write. There is a bit more overhead in setting up the views, but the benefits in timesaving later are huge. Plus it allows reusability.

Comment: @user1666620: the question that you pointed answers in nothing to my quesiton. I know that I should use ViewModels, I am just not sure how they can help me in this specific case. Please remove the vote to close.

Comment: tbh if you find yourself using that many if and else statements to decide what to show/hide, I would just split the logic out into different views and viewmodels, and let the controller decide which view should be used based on a user's roles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public OtherModel Model { get; set; }
    public bool IsSomethingHere
    {
        get
        {
            return (User.isHelpDesk && Model.MaterialStatusId == MatStatus.A1HelpDeskProductProposal) ||
                (User.isProcurement && Model.MaterialStatusId == MatStatus.A4PurchasingDptValidation);
        }
    }
    public bool IsSomethingElseHere
    {
        get
        {
            return User.isHelpDesk || User.isProcurement || User.isDirector || User.isManager;
        }
    }
}
```

View models are useful to aggregate data and conditionals. You can give it meaningful property names to make it easy to follow in the View.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on the @Beautifulcoder answer... in general a ViewModel is loaded in the controller action. There, you can do all the calculation, in such a way that your view only need to display what you pass to it.

Besides using ViewModels, you can have this complex logic in a view, but the markup inside each "IF" block can be put in a partial view, and call it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName", Model)
```

That way, you will handle the evolution of each section separately... and it is most likely that your complex view is less changed that each partial.